# Runtime 91 Variable not set - Sharing Variable between Forms and Modules

Tags: vba, excel

I think I'm misunderstanding something simple here, as usual, some fundamental principle I have yet to learn.

Anyway, I am trying to set up a combobox for the purpose of selecting from the active workbooks and passing the workbook name to a variable for use in future code.

However, I could only get this to work by setting said variable type as Variant, and after the code finishes executing I am still getting an error... so what's going on there then?

```
Private Sub cmdPopulate_Click()

If cmbWorkbooks.Value <> "" Then
    selectedWorkbook = cmbWorkbooks.Value
    Call populateChecklist
End If

Unload Me

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

For Each wb In Workbooks
    cmbWorkbooks.AddItem wb.Name
Next wb

Me.Show

End Sub

Public wb As Workbook
Public ws As Worksheet
Public selectedWorkbook As Variant

Sub populateChecklist()

MsgBox "hello " & selectedWorkbook

End Sub
```

Edit:

To clarify the error I receive upon finished execution is:
Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set

Edit2:
ok I think I've figured it out...
I commented out everything by degrees until I found the culprit.

It seems to be caused by Me.Show in the userform_Initialize sub, which is apparently redundant code anyway!

Comment: Please indicate which line is producing the error.

Comment: Well that's just it... when I run this no line is indicated, but I still get the error, which is sort of annoying. I'm fairly sure it is happening because of selectedWorkbook, so line 4, and... Public selectedWorkbook As Variant

Comment: `wb.Name` returns a string with the name of the workbook. You need a string variable to store that variable. Try `Public selectedWorkbook As String`. Also, you say in your question *...nd after the code finishes executing I am still getting an error...***. Could you please be more precise? There are thousands of errors in VBA, we need more information to help :)

Comment: Try debugging your code step by step. Use F8 to execute your code, and then execute line by line. that way you can locate the error.[How to debug](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)

Comment: Still seems to be producing the error even with the String type... and error Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: Why not evolve to passing parameters to sub procedures?

Comment: could you explain that a bit further?

Comment: You need to locate the line that raises error 91.

Comment: I think I found it... see edits above! Not what I expected o_o